# Create new Asset Kinds

Tags: assets

I have updated my `craft/config/general.php` file to allow some new file types to be uploaded to my site.

```
'extraAllowedFileExtensions' => 'bim, dwg, rvt'
```

When I output these file assets in the template, I would like to be able to use the {{ asset.kind }} property to output "PDF" or whatever name for my additional types.

Currently I see `unknown` for each of my new types.

I've had a look in the [documentation](https://craftcms.com/classreference/helpers/IOHelper#getFileKinds-detail) for the IOHelper Class but could not see a way to add additional definitions.

Answer (score 2):

Currently, the "file kinds" list is [hard-coded](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/Craft-Release/blob/master/app/helpers/IOHelper.php#L1907-L1932) and doesn't expose itself to a config setting or plugins.

You can definitely make a [feature request](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues) to open it up, though!

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question. Perhaps this is more a feature request?

Comment: Updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I've raised a request here: https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues/1584